# In the figure given below, angle pqr equals angle qrs equals angle tur equals 90 degrees. Pq equals 8 sr equals 12 and ur equals 6. Find tu

Tags: triangles

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/fU02a.jpg)

In the figure given below, angle pqr equals angle qrs equals angle tur equals 90 degrees. Pq equals 8 sr equals 12 and ur equals 6. Find tu

Comment: How about you flip the picture? It's not very nice to look at an upside-down figure.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let's denote $TU= x$ and $QU = y$. Now, from similar triangles, we obtain
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{12-x}{6} &= \frac{12}{y+6} &= \frac{x}{y} \\
\frac{8}{y+6}  &= \frac{8-x}{y}  &= \frac{x}{6}
\end{array}
\right.
\Rightarrow
\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{y}{x} = \frac{y+6}{12} \\
\frac{x}{6} = \frac{8-x}{y}
\end{array}
\right.
\Rightarrow
\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
12y &= xy+ 6x \\
xy &= 48 - 6x 
\end{array}
\right.
\Rightarrow 12y = 48 \Rightarrow y = 4
$$
Substituting this to the second line of the first result, we get
$$
\frac{8-x}{4} = \frac{x}{6} \Rightarrow x= \frac{24}{5}
$$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Hint. Let $QU=x$, $TU=y$. Use similarity of next triangles: $\triangle PQR\sim \triangle TUR$  and $\triangle SRQ\sim \triangle TUQ$. Then: $\frac{8}{6+x}=\frac{y}{6}$ and $\frac{12}{6+x}=\frac{y}{x}$ Comparing them find $x$ and then $y$.